# Facing issue while creating custom event entries inside firebase analytics console

Tags: google-bigquery, google-analytics, firebase-analytics, firebase-console

I am able to created total 50 events and after that create button remains disabled, it says stream has reached the limit for created events. However as per google documentation [limit is up to 500 distinct events](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics).

See the screenshot and below is error I am facing.

> This stream has reached the limit for created events. Please bring
> down the number of created events below limit before you can create
> new ones.

[image]

Please suggest the solution If anyone having any clue here. Thanks in advance!